# creating an LAS file from a jpeg or tiff image based on given coordinates

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, ocr, payumoney

Is it possible to create an LAS file from an image like the one provided below, referenced to the scales provided on the image? I will Venmo 25$ to anyone who can show me how to do this.

[Say you have a continuous line like so from depth 0 to 100(y-axis) and from intensity 0 to 100(x-axis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XJJ0.jpg)